# dotnet tool update not getting latest version in nuget

Tags: nuget, dotnet-tool

I'm playing with dotnet-tool and nuget; I noticed that if I push a refresh nameOfPackage.nupkg to the nuget repo and then run `dotnet tool update -g nameOfPackage` it does not take the new package version.

I have to force a cache clear to get it to take the latest one.

```
dotnet nuget locals http-cache -c
```

I previously installed the package doing

```
dotnet tool update -g nameOfPackage
```

Is this by design? Do I have to flush the cache every single time to make sure there are no updates to the tool?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the `--no-cache` option forces the update.

```
dotnet tool update -g nameOfPackage --no-cache
```

[image]

Source: [dotnet tool update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-tool-update)

Comment: I had this issue with GitHub Nuget feed. Somehow the latest version isn't updated. `--no-cache` helped.